# Select element by path in remote webpage

Tags: powershell, web-scraping, selectnodes

I am trying to find a way to select an element from a remote webpage by it’s path. The element does not have id so I need to use the path.

I get the page like this:

$page = invoke-WebRequest -Uri ‘server address’

I can see the content with $page.content

I need to get the element at /html/body/p[6]

How ?

Comment: Assuming you're using Windows PowerShell: `$page.ParsedHtml.body.childNodes |? TagName -eq p |select -Index 7`

Comment: What’s $r ? Response ?

Comment: Sorry, mistyped, fixed now

Comment: Doesn’t work. For some reason the p I am looking for is in childNodes[8]. Using that nothing is returned. Using yours something else is returned.

Comment: `Select -Index 8` then :)

Comment: I used $page.ParsedHtml.body.childNodes[8] |? TagName -eq p |select innertext and it works

Comment: Doesn’t work using -index 8 and childNodes (without [8])